# Issues with Code Running on Two-Socket PC

Tags: c, openmp

I'm running the following code on a Dual-socket Intel Xeon Platinum 8378A CPU under Windows 11 Workstation. I use the MSYS2 GCC64 compiler of the latest version (13.2.0). For some unclear reason, this code is only running on half of the processor cores. How can I maximize processor utilization?

[image: Processor load]

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define N 1000 // Dimensions

int main() {
    int A[N][N], B[N][N], C[N][N];
    int i, j, k;

    // Matrices init
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            A[i][j] = i + j;
            B[i][j] = i - j;
        }
    }

    // Multiplication
    #pragma omp parallel for private(i, j, k)
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            C[i][j] = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < N; k++) {
                C[i][j] += A[i][k] * B[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    // Output
    printf("The result is:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            printf("%d\t", C[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 5000 x 5000 x 4 (or 8) x 3 is either 300Mb or 600Mb for 3 arrays... How much stack space have you declared?

Comment: This code is just a sample as I need to post some code, all of my codes including dynamic memory declaration RUNS on half of cores. Thats it! Im not asking about stack space declaration - it can be defined as much as I need

Comment: Your CPUs have 64 *physical* cores and consequently OpenMP spawns 64 threads. The 64 other cores are *logical* cores, and most of time using them doesn't improve the performances. Depending on how OpenMP is configured on your system you can force it using more threads, either with the environment variable `OMP_NUM_THREADS` or with the function `set_omp_num_threads()` in the code

Comment: When you settle the core question (Im going with @PierU's explanation) you will run into performance problems because of an issue called "first touch". All your memory will be "instantiated" on one socket, so the other socket has to go through NUMA access. Remedy: make your initialization an OMP parallel loop. This is independent of static/dynamic allocation.